# "Pending edits" in Stack Overflow application (iPhone)

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, ios-app

I recently reached 2000 reputation points, which allowed me to see pending edits and `approve`/`refuse` them on the Stack Overflow desktop site. But this feature (accessed by clicking the brown number on the top-right hand of the website) seems to be missing from the mobile application, and especially the iPhone app.

I spend lots of time on this app, but making a complete question with code and fiddle is a somewhere between hard and impossible on a mobile. However checking pending edits is something technically easy to handle on such a device, but I can't find it.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't missing anything; the API that the Stack Exchange apps use do not support review tasks. Currently, the only way to review questions, answers and suggested edits is through the browser.

You can view the API documentation [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)  (at the time of this answer, v2.2).

Comment: I tried to find an already asked question about this, but my english wording didn't allow me to find the exact terms for the request. Fact is, my question is a duplicate. Thank you anyway for your answer and the link you provided.